# Can others read my DNS entries?

Tags: domain-name-system

Suppose I define an A record in my DNS for host foo.example.com. If nobody knows about the existence of foo.example.com, but do about example.com, could someone somehow query the DNS records of example.com to return that name foo.example.com?

Comment: DNS records are public. That's kind of the whole point of them.

Comment: @Jenny D, That's not what he's asking.

Comment: @haim770 It's not, but it's still important to note for readers in passing. Internet facing DNS is not where one puts things that they don't want on public record. (i.e. private IPs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is it depends.  If the user can guess the name, like www, then yes they can.  If you use more esoteric names the user would only be able to get arbitrary records if they were able to do what's called a [zone transfer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5936), which sends the entire domain's data.

Most nameservers disallow zone transfers by default.  You can test yours here:

https://tools.digitalpoint.com/zone-transfer?domain=example.com

Comment: You can also test yourself by using `dig -t AXFR domain.com` you'll either get a "denied" message or it'll dump all the zone records.

Comment: @Nathan With the caveat that the `dig` should be performed from outside the network, otherwise you risk a false positive.

Answer (score 3):

From end-user perspective of view, no. DNS will only return results for specific Hostname (or IP address for reverse-lookup).

Yet, many DNS servers support the feature known as **Zone Transfer**, that basically can dump all zone file data to another machine.

By doing so, the server can save some load by letting all other DNS servers have the full zone file instead of delegating the resolve request to it.

In reality, most DNS Administrators will not allow Zone Transfer for obvious (security) reasons.

If you want to try it yourself, use `nslookup` (in Windows):

```
//#requesting for google.com dns server
set q=ns
google.com

#response is: primary name server = ns1.google.com

server ns1.google.com    
ls -d google.com //#this is the zone transfer request
```

More in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone_transfer)

Comment: If I could accept 2 answers I would. This answer is also very helpful, thank you!